# (MC 1.8) Is it possible to change FallingSand's damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can you increase the damage that the entity FallingSand does to you? Like a damage tag? I want falling anvils to deal 9 damage each or otherwise be a 3 hit kill to players. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For falling sand there is a `{FallHurtMax}` and a `{FallHurtAmount}` datatag.

`{FallHurtMax}` is used to change the max damage the falling sand can do.

`{FallHurtAmount}` is the variable multiplied against FallDistance to calculate how much damage to do. By default is is always 2.

Also if you are using the /summon command to spawn them in don't forget to add the tag `{HurtEntities}` this will make the fallingsand entity deal fall damage.

A summon command for a falling anvil that always does 9 damage no matter how far it falls would look something like this.

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Block:anvil,Data:0,Time:1,HurtEntities:1,FallHurtMax:9,FallHurtAmount:1000}
```

If you have anymore questions on this topic let me know via comments and I'll try my best to answer them.